# Couchbase get / getMulti fails on timeout in node.js

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I'm new with Couchbase and trying to use the couchbase module 1.2.1, the connection to the DB seems to work fine, but the get and getMulti operations are failing and the error I'm getting is "Operation timed out".
I tried to increase the timeout, but it didn't help.

```
var db = new couchbase.Connection({ host:'localhost:8091', bucket:'beer-sample'},
   function(err){
         if (err){
         throw err; // not getting here
   }
});


 db.get("id", function(err, result) {
            if (!err && result){ // getting error
                req.id = result;
            }
  });
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are various reasons why this may occur. Are you able to access the administration interface and witness the incoming operation?

Comment: It looks like the operation does not get there. The administration interface does not detect any operations on the bucket.

Comment: Perhaps try the host as ["127.0.0.1:8091"]. Make sure you do not have any firewalls or anything else that may be blocking the request.

Comment: Do you have multiple nodes in the cluster? Tried rebooting couchbase? On smaller machines I have had this issue, such as virtual machines.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to reinstall Couchbase Server and try again using a host of `127.0.0.1:8091`.

What version of Couchbase Server, and what platform/architecture you are using would also be helpful to know.

Comment: I reinstalled the Couchbase Server and the get works on 90% of the time, but still no luck with the getMulti. I'm using version 2.2.0 enterprise edition (build-821) of Couchbase on Windows.